# WooCommerce: Bulk change product type from simple to external / affiliate

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, woocommerce

After trying to find the solution myself for a long time I decided to ask for help.

I have 500+ products in my datase but they are marked as downloadable and virtual, instead of external.
I want to change them all to external products.
Currenlty the product link is entered in the field of the "simple download"-type.

I tried to change it through mysql, but I cant seem to figure out how to change the product type.

Anyone got a solution for me?

Answer (score 0):

In phpMyAdmin, open your table, Search > Find and replace.

Comment: That doesnt work, because it is not only the product type table that has to change. I used an migration plugin to export and reimport the products as a solution to my problem.